# Data in data grid view won't show visually C# SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, user-interface, datagrid, datagridview

I have this data grid view like this:

[image]

But it should be like this:

[image]

The data is successfully fetched but I have to drag the cells so the data can be shown.
This is the code:

```
private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            sqlConnStaff();
            groupBoxRoom.Visible = false;
            groupBoxDPenghuni.Visible = false;
            groupBoxPenghasilan.Visible = false;
            groupBoxPenghuni.Visible = false;
            groupBoxStaff.Visible = true;
            GroupBox_AddResident_Resident.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_AddResident_Room.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_AddResident1.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_DeleteResident_Resident.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_DeleteResident1.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_Resident.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_Update_Room.Visible = false;
            GroupBox_UpdateResident1.Visible = false;
        }

private void sqlConnStaff()
        {
            BindingSource dbBindSource = new BindingSource();

            SqlCommand com;
            com = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);

            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = "view_staff";

            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

            IDCabang = new SqlParameter();
            IDCabang.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            IDCabang.Size = 5;
            IDCabang.ParameterName = "@IDCabang";
            IDCabang.Value = IDCabangC;
            IDCabang.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            com.Parameters.Add(IDCabang);

            con.Open();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            dbBindSource.DataSource = table;

            dataGridView3.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
            // you can make it grid readonly.
            dataGridView3.ReadOnly = true;
            // finally bind the data to the grid
            dataGridView3.DataSource = dbBindSource;

            con.Close();
        }
```

Whats wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem is not with your c# code but the coloring scheme. When you select cells the data is visible, which means you must change fore color to something other than white.